# How .net web service is doing JSON serializaion

Tags: c#, .net, json, service, web

I have develop web service in c# .net. I declare methods as:

```
public interface IServiceMeinMedicusApp
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "GetParamn/value")]
    string GetParamn(int value);
}
```

I also have java client which is generated according to provided WSDL. In java client I access web service methods simply by calling the equivalent Java methods.

My question is: How Web service and web client doing JSON serialization. Could somebody access to my web service by sending simple JSON format to proper address? What should I provide him, what kind of format should be data in JSON and where should be sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I provide him, what kind of format should be data in JSON and where should be sent?

It's either a client generated from WSDL, or some manual solution. REST doesn't do metadata, so any consumer won't know what operations and 'data contracts' are available.

Getting Java to consume a WCF WSDL and vice versa isn't always that straightforward, but still easier than manually creating a strongly-typed REST client. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

You can perhaps capture requests using Fiddler, to inspect what your client sends to the service. You can then extract the data and URL format to show to other developers that want to access your service.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What do you think about workaround for our customer who prefer strict JSON communication: to create my own client which will receive JSON requests, read parameters, call web service method, pack response back in JSON and return to requester.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the web address of the hosted web service. Since you have set ResponseFormat as WebmessageFormat.Json  the JSON serialization is happening.